# How to pipe a long-lasting command until either the first match or timing out?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have a remote syslog tailer for a device that, if a condition is present, would contain a particular string every about 15 seconds or so. It can be detected by running it as such:

```
(timeout 20 remote-logger 2>&1) | grep -m 1 KEY
```

(Using a higher timeout value to compensate for potential jitters)

Is there a way to short-circuit this if the KEY string is found earlier?

Comment: How much non-matching content is there? (Would it be inefficient to use shell-native logic to filter it out?)

Comment: Also -- does your `remote-logger` tool buffer its output when that output is to a pipeline?

Comment: And which exact version of bash? (Very new ones give you access to the PID of process substitution commands).

Comment: The remote-logger tool does not buffer. And there's a lot of non-matching content (multiple messages per second).

It's the bash 3.2 from macOS (though if there's any bash 4.4+ solutions that are really helpful I can install it with Homebrew). timeout comes from GNU coreutils.

Comment: If it's multiple messages per second, vs multiple megabytes per second, then a shell loop will more than suffice for filtering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In bash 4.4 with a GNU toolchain, you can do the following:

```
exec 3< <(stdbuf -oL remote-logger | grep --line-buffered -m 1 KEY); pid=$!
read -t 20 -r key <&3
kill "$pid"
```

Prior to 4.4, `$!` won't capture the PID of a process substitution, so you won't be able to execute a `kill` -- but the other parts should work.

---

Incidentally, you can also do the filtering natively in shell (with lower throughput, but lesser pipeline startup costs):

```
result=
while IFS= read -r line; do
  case $line in
    *KEY*) result=$line;;
    *) continue;;
  esac
done < <(timeout 20 remote-logger)
```

Comment: If remote-logger terminates as soon as stdout will be closed, like `tail` for example, `timeout 20 stdbuf -oL tail -f log.file | stdbuf -oL grep PATTERN  -m1` should be enough since `-m1` will make `grep` terminate as soon as a match is found, which leads to closing the pipe.

Comment: Hmm. I was concerned we could hang on until the next match in the log file (at which point `grep`'s attempt to write would fail).

Comment: Sure. But once `grep` exits, `remote-logger`'s attempts to write will fail; it's `grep` that's the immediately prior piece of the chain.

Comment: I tested with `tail` (since I don't have remote-logger) and that worked fine. I mean what should a program that writes line buffered should do other than fail when stdout get's closed?

Comment: `IFS=read -r -d '' line` never returns for me, but a simplified version does what I need:

   `while read line; do
     if echo $line | grep "$KEY" >/dev/null; then echo FOUND; break; fi
  done < <(timeout 20 remote-logger)`

Comment: Oops -- `-d ''` is looking for a NUL. Sorry about that, misapplied finger memory from the wrong place. `while IFS= read -r line` is still more correct than the original code (avoids trimming leading and trailing whitespace or removing backslash literals).